# Multiplying and Adding Large Numbers

Tags: c++, number-systems

Lately, I've been working on the Euler projects. I just started coding in C++ and could really use some feedback. Basically, I wrote a program to calculate the factorial of any number between 1 and 100 (I have not tested it above 100).

I looked into the Boost library, but it seemed a little bit to easy, so I wrote some algorithms on my own.

Anyway, I would really like some comments about whether this is efficient or not, and if I can somehow optimize the algorithms? I hope this post is within the scope of the forum, since it is my first.

I first convert two integers to vectors, storing each digit separately:

```
// Converting number to vector
std::vector<int> LargeNumber(int number) {
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    while (number > 0) {
        numbers.push_back(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Then I pass the vectors on to one of these two functions, depending on whether I want to add or multiply:

```
// Adds large numbers
std::vector<int> addition(std::vector<int> max, std::vector<int> min) {
    if (max.size() < min.size()) {
        max.swap(min);
    }
    std::vector<int> sum;
    int rest = 0;    

    for (int i = 0; i < min.size(); i++) {
        int c = min[i] + max[i] + rest;
        sum.push_back(c % 10);
        rest = c / 10;
    }

    for (int i = min.size(); i < max.size(); i++) {
        int c = max[i] + rest;
        sum.push_back(c % 10);
        rest = c / 10;
    }
    while (rest > 0) {
        sum.push_back(rest % 10);
        rest /= 10;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

---

```
// Multiplying large numbers
std::vector<int> multiplication(std::vector<int> max, std::vector<int> min) {
    if (max.size() < min.size()) {
        max.swap(min);
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> sums;
    std::vector<int> sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < min.size(); i++) {
        sum.resize(0);
        int n = i;
        while (n > 0) {
            sum.push_back(0);
            n--;
        }
        int rest = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < max.size(); j++) {
            int c = max[j] * min[i] + rest;
            sum.push_back(c % 10);
            rest = c / 10;
        }
        while (rest > 0) {
            sum.push_back(rest % 10);
            rest /= 10;
        }
        sums.push_back(sum);
    }
    sum.resize(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < sums.size(); i++) {
        sum = addition(sum, sums[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I can then calculate the factorial as:

```
#include <vector>
int main () {
    // Calculating the factorial of the number N
    int N = 100;
    std::vector<int> fac;
    sum.push_back(1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        fac = multiplication(sum, LargeNumber(i));
    }
    // Printing the result
    std::cout << "The factorial of " << N << ": " <<  std::endl;
    for (int i = sum.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << fac[i];
    } std::cout << std::endl; 
}
```

Since I am very new to C++, it is hard for me to know what exactly to ask for, so any comment is very welcome.

Comment: Your `LargeNumber` won't work on zero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really worth making your big number be a class.  This will give you the ability to

- change the internal representation without altering client code
- write operators (`+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `<`, `==`, `<<` and more) that work just like they do for other numbers
- specialize numeric limits and other traits classes so they can be used as arithmetic types in algorithms. For example, you might like a `std::complex<BigNum>`.  You can have one, but a `std::complex<std::vector<int>>` isn't going to work.
- add literal operators so that you can write them naturally in your source code.

You don't have to do all the above at once, of course.  But I recommend you read the review of [Implementation of a Rational Number class in C++](/q/157881) to see how an arithmetic class can work.

Your `main()` would then be isolated from the implementation details, and look something like

```
#include <bignum>

int main () {
    int N = 100;
    auto fac = 1_big;
    do {
        fac *= N;
    } while (--N > 0);

    std::cout << "100! = " << fac << std::endl;
}
```

---

### Space efficiency

Once you have your class, you'll observe that writing one digit in each `int` is quite wasteful.  `char` is defined to include at least `0` to `127` so you could store two digits (`0` to `100`) in each element of a vector of characters.

If you've made your big number a class, it's then easier to do this in two steps - first store one digit in each character, and then widen to 2 per char.  There are more space-efficient encodings; you'll have to decide where the trade-off between space and time lies for your needs.

---

### Temporary values in multiplication

In your long multiplication, you store all the intermediate results before adding them together.  You can save some of this space by using an *accumulator* variable to add the results as you go, like this pseudo-code:

```python
accumulator = 0
for i in digits
     tmp = arg1 * i
     accumulator += tmp
return accumulator
```

Then you no longer need to have a vector of partial products throughout the function.

---

## Working example

Here's what I implemented, following the notes above.  It's the absolute minimum needed to calculate factorials.  Several features are left as an exercise:

- Implement a user-defined literal that accepts longer numbers than `unsigned long long` can represent
- Support negative numbers
- Implement the other arithmetic and relational operators
- Make more of the implementation `constexpr` so it can be evaluated during compilation

```
#include <vector>
#include <iosfwd>

class Bignum
{
    static constexpr char max_digit = 100;

    std::vector<char> digits = {};   // smallest centits first

public:
    Bignum(unsigned long long int n)
    {
        while (n) {
            digits.push_back(n % max_digit);
            n /= max_digit;
        }
    }
    // copy constructor and assignment operator can be defaulted

    Bignum& operator+=(const Bignum& other);
    Bignum operator+(const Bignum& other) const;

    Bignum& operator*=(const Bignum& other);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Bignum&);

private:
    // helper functions
    Bignum& halve();
    Bignum& trim();
};

Bignum operator""_big(unsigned long long n) { return n; }


// IMPLEMENTATION

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

Bignum& Bignum::operator+=(const Bignum& other)
{
    int sum = 0;
    auto i = digits.begin();
    auto j = other.digits.begin();
    bool in = true;             // until i reaches digits.end()
    bool jn = true;
    while ((in &= i != digits.end()) | (jn &= j != other.digits.end()) || sum) {
        if (jn)
            sum += *j++;
        if (in) {
            sum += *i;
            *i++ = sum % max_digit;
        } else {
            digits.push_back(sum % max_digit);
        }
        sum /= max_digit;       // carry to next digit
    }
    return *this;
}

Bignum Bignum::operator+(const Bignum& other) const
{
    return Bignum{*this} += other;
}


Bignum& Bignum::operator*=(const Bignum& other)
{
    Bignum a = *this, b = other;
    if (a.digits.size() > b.digits.size())
        std::swap(a, b);

    digits.clear();
    while (a.digits.size() > 0) {
        if (a.digits.front() % 2)
            *this += b;
        a.halve();
        b += b;
    }
    return *this;
}

Bignum& Bignum::halve()
{
    int carry = 0;
    for (auto i = digits.rbegin();  i != digits.rend();  ++i) {
        carry *= max_digit;
        carry += *i;
        *i = carry / 2;
        carry = carry % 2;
    }
    return trim();
}

Bignum& Bignum::trim()
{
    while (digits.size() > 0 && !digits.back())
        digits.pop_back();
    return *this;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Bignum& n)
{
    if (n.digits.size() == 0)
        return out << '0';

    bool z = false;             // track leading zeros
    for (auto i = n.digits.rbegin();  i != n.digits.rend();  ++i) {
        int n = *i;
        if (z |= n/10)
            out << n/10;
        if (z |= n)
            out << n % 10;
    }

    return out;
}


// PROGRAM

int main () {
    const int N = 100;
    auto fac = 1_big;

    for (int i = 1;  i < N;  ++i) {
        fac *= i;
        std::cout << i << "! = " << fac << std::endl;
    };
}
```